# Is it possible to dynamically find an array of items with a Spring controller?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want a controller which can take in a mapped entity with varying attributes assigned to it and find an array of similar entities?

Ex: Controller Method

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/get", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String get(@ModelAttribute("User") User user) {
        ArrayList<User> users = repository.someMethod(user);
        return users.toString();
    }
```

Going to URL:

```
localhost:8181/get?name=Bob&ZipCode=35146
```

returns an ArrayList from the database for all instances of User with name=Bob and ZipCode=35146

Going to URL:

```
localhost:8181/get?name=Bob&state=Missouri
```

returns an ArrayList from the database for all instances of User with name=Bob and state=Missouri

Is there a simple Spring (or any other) way of achieving this without a complicated method that chooses from several different queries on the repository with slight deviations?

Comment: I was going to answer, but that link should do you.